# Scrapy Logging Level Change

Tags: python-3.x, logging, scrapy

I'm trying to start scrapy spider from my scripty as shown in [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)

```
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='log.txt',
    format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    level=logging.CRITICAL
)
configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

process.crawl('1740')
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

I want to configure the **logging level of my spider** but even if i do not install root logger handler and configure my basic config with *logging.basicConfig* method it does not obey the determinded level.

```
INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['collector.pipelines.CollectorPipeline']
INFO: Spider opened
INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

It is following format and file name determined in basicConfig but it does not use logging level. I do not determine logging level other then this place.

**NOTE:** There is not any other place which i import logging or change logging level.

Answer (score 25):

For scrapy itself you should define logging settings in `settings.py` [as described in the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html?highlight=logging#logging-settings)

so in `settings.py` you can set:

```
LOG_LEVEL = 'ERROR'  # to only display errors
LOG_FORMAT = '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'
LOG_FILE = 'log.txt'
```

Comment: yes it does. First; even if i changed that setting it only applies on stdout logs. For example if i changed LOG_ENABLED to False it is not generating logs to stdout but it is continuing to generate for file determined in main (above). The second problem with this approach is; it is a global setting. I want to change logger's settings separately.

Comment: If one adds `LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'` are the other settings mandatory? I've set mine to `DEBUG` but I'm not getting anything extra!